# SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5.4

I am trying to run this query

```
$claims = Claim::wherein('policy_id', $userPolicyIds)->where('claim_settlement_status', 'Accepted')->wherebetween('intimation_date', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();
```

Here, `$userPolicyIds` can have thousands of policy ids. Is there any way I can increase the maximum number of parameters in SQL server? If not, could anyone help me find a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by running this raw query

```
SELECT claims.*, policies.* FROM claims INNER JOIN policies ON claims.policy_id = policies.id 
                    WHERE policy_id IN $userPolicyIds AND claim_settlement_status = 'Accepted' AND intimation_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate';
```

Here, `$userPolicyIds` is a string like this `('123456','654321','456789')`. This query is a bit slow, I'll admit that. But the number of policy ids is always going to a very big number and I wanted a quick fix.

Answer (score 3):

The `wherein` method creates an SQL fragment of the form `WHERE policy_id IN (userPolicyIds[0], userPolicyIds[1], userPolicyIds[2]..., userPolicyIds[MAX])`.  In other words, the entire collection is unwrapped into the SQL statement.  The result is a ***HUGE*** SQL statement that SQL Server refuses to execute.

This is a well known limitation of Microsoft SQL Server.  And it is a hard limit, because there appears to be no option for changing it.  But SQL Server can hardly be blamed for having this limit, because trying to execute a query with as many as 2000 parameters is an unhealthy situation that you should not have put yourself into in the first place.

So, even if there was a way to change the limit, it would still be advisable to leave the limit as it is, and restructure your code instead, so that this unhealthy situation does not arise.

You have at least a couple of options:

- Break your query down to batches of, say, 2000 items each.
- Add your fields into a temporary table and make your query join that table.

Personally, I would go with the second option, since it will perform much better than anything else, and it is arbitrarily scalable.

Comment: I executed this query in SQL Server : select * from [claims] where [policy_id] in (select id from policies) and [claim_settlement_status] = 'Accepted'. It ran very smoothly without any problems. In this query there are even more policy ids, close to a million. How can this be a limitation of SQL server if it can run this query? Just curious

Comment: Oh, you asked how to "increase the maximum number of parameters in SQL server" so I thought you understood what the problem is.  I amended my answer to explain what is going on.  The number of parameters that you can pass to an SQL query has absolutely nothing to do with the number of results that can be returned by an SQL query.

Comment: @ShateelAhmed - is that the actual nature of the process that you're working with - that the policy ids are drawn from another table? If so, you ought to update your question with such details and then look to write a *single* query that processes all of the data in SQL, rather than trying to assemble the result set via multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

just use prepare driver_options (PDO::prepare)

PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdo-prepare

and split where in on peaces (where (column in [...]) or column in [...])

Comment: This worked for me locally, but for some reason on the production server I'm getting `The given attribute is only supported on the PDOStatement object.` as an Exception message for every query from this.